# License plate input in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

In my application I am asking users to write down their license plate without any dashes. It's only used for license plates in the Netherlands, which always consist of a combination of numbers and letters which always have a length of 6 characters. My question is:

How can I make sure the input is always 6 digits long?

I have a < p >-tag in the _form.html.erb stating the user should only write down their license plate without dashes but that is, of course, not the best way to do.

In my _form.html.erb I've written

```
<strong><%= f.label :license_plate, 'Kenteken' %></strong><br />
<%= f.text_field :license_plate %>
```

My model contains the line

```
validates :license_plate, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => {:minimum => 6, :maximum => 6}
```

If you need more information, I'm happily willing to share. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I would like to remove any whitespaces and dashes from the user input. How should I write it in code?

Comment: Are you wanting to limit the input to 6 characters or strip the value entered to remove whitespace, dashes etc. ?

Comment: sawa, I made a mistake, it was supposed to be numbers & letters, but I made an edit.

Comment: muttonlamb, it would be best if I could remove the dashes, so if users would enter ABC123 or AB-C1-23 it wouldn't matter.

Comment: If you have a form, it's more user-friendly to validate before the form is submitted. Entering something, submitting it, then having to fix it is more irritating than entering something, moving to the next field and being notified. This is easy to do in JavaScript and allows you to also reposition the cursor in the field in question, along with cleaning out characters that are not acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `before_validation` callback to remove unwanted characters:

```
before_validation :clean_data

def clean_data
  self.license_plate = self.license_plate.gsub(/[ \-]/, '') unless self.license_plate.nil?
end
```